# Problems with website codes in different browsers

Tags: html, browser

I have this code that is working perfectly for Firefox but when I try to get IE to play the audio files Error (Playback was aborted)

I don't want to optimize my site for just one browser so am wondering what I'm doing wrong.

```
<html>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>...</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1 ALIGN="CENTER">...</H1>
<P ALIGN="CENTER"> <IMG SRC="../picture/1.jpg"></P>
<P ALIGN="CENTER"> ...</P>
<P ALIGN="CENTER"> <audio controls><source src="../audio/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio></P>
<P ALIGN="CENTER"> ...</P>
<P ALIGN="CENTER"> <audio controls><source src="../audio/2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio></P>
<P ALIGN="CENTER"> ...</P>
<P ALIGN="CENTER"> <audio controls><source src="../audio/3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio></P>
<P ALIGN="CENTER"> ...</P>
<P ALIGN="CENTER"> <audio controls><source src="../audio/4.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio></P>
</BODY>
</html>
```

I have edit the titles out. Why does IE Restrict scripts or active X controls?

[image: ERROR 1]
[image: ERROR 2]

Comment: could you provide us the site link or show us the erro and the full code?

Comment: I have not uploaded this to a web server yet. I will add pictures of the errors.

Comment: It looks like if I just command it to allow it works but I would like to know why exactly it does not work so perfectly as Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a safety feature. As you are running the file locally (not on a server or trusted site), Internet Explorer blocks the ActiveX controls and scripts because it considers that they may unsafe or harmful to your computer. I guess the idea is that IE doesn't know if you developed that page yourself, or if you downloaded it from somewhere potentially dangerous.

In [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/149068/how-to-add-a-local-file-to-trusted-zone-in-ie8) there is a possible solution for this. It is from 2010, but it sill applies to IE11:

1. Open IE
2. Go to tools > Internet options
3. Click on the advanced tab
4. Check the box "Allow active content to run in files on My Computer*"
5. Restart the computer

[image: Internet options with mandatory handfree circle to highlight option]

Comment: So this will not be an issue when the website goes live?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It shouldn't be a problem once it is uploaded to a server (unless the site is in the list of restricted sites, but you could fix that in the Internet Options too)